# PYTHON - Jogo do NIM (problema com o correção do computador começar ou não)

Tags: python

Objetivo

Você deverá escrever um programa na linguagem Python, versão 3, que permita a uma "vítima" jogar o NIM contra o computador. O computador, é claro, deverá seguir a estratégia vencedora descrita acima.

Sejam n o número de peças inicial e m o número máximo de peças que é possível retirar em uma rodada. Para garantir que o computador ganhe sempre, é preciso considerar os dois cenários possíveis para o início do jogo:

**Se n é múltiplo de (m+1), o computador deve ser "generoso" e convidar o jogador a iniciar a partida**;
*Caso contrário, o computador toma a inciativa de começar o jogo*.
Uma vez iniciado o jogo, a estratégia do computador para ganhar consiste em deixar sempre um número de peças que seja múltiplo de (m+1) ao jogador. Caso isso não seja possível, deverá tirar o número máximo de peças possíveis.

**Seu trabalho, então, será implementar o Jogo e fazer com que o computador se utilize da estratégia vencedora.**

Veja um exemplo de como deve funcionar o jogo:

```html
$ > python3 jogo_nim.py

Bem-vindo ao jogo do NIM! Escolha:

1 - para jogar uma partida isolada
2 - para jogar um campeonato 2

Voce escolheu um campeonato!

**** Rodada 1 ****

Quantas peças? 3
Limite de peças por jogada? 1

Computador começa!

O computador tirou uma peça.
Agora restam 2 peças no tabuleiro.

Quantas peças você vai tirar? 2

Oops! Jogada inválida! Tente de novo.

Quantas peças você vai tirar? 1

Você tirou uma peça.
Agora resta apenas uma peça no tabuleiro.

O computador tirou uma peça.
Fim do jogo! O computador ganhou!

**** Rodada 2 ****

Quantas peças? 3
Limite de peças por jogada? 2

Voce começa!

Quantas peças você vai tirar? 2 
Voce tirou 2 peças.
Agora resta apenas uma peça no tabuleiro.

O computador tirou uma peça.
Fim do jogo! O computador ganhou!

**** Rodada 3 ****

Quantas peças? 4
Limite de peças por jogada? 3

Voce começa!

Quantas peças você vai tirar? 2
Voce tirou 2 peças.
Agora restam 2 peças no tabuleiro.

O computador tirou 2 peças.
Fim do jogo! O computador ganhou!

**** Final do campeonato! ****

Placar: Você 0 X 3 Computador
```

Eu fiz o código em cima do código do Anderson Carlos Woss (https://ideone.com/GfaZyF) é esse:

```html
tipo_jogo = 0
 
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m):
    if n <= m:
        return n
    else:
        quantia = n % (m+1)
        if quantia > 0:
            return quantia
        return m
 
def usuario_escolhe_jogada(n, m):
    jogada = 0
    while jogada == 0:
        jogada = int(input("Quantas peças você vai tirar? "))
        if jogada > n or jogada < 1 or jogada > m:
            print("Oops! Jogada inválida! Tente de novo.")
            jogada = 0
    return jogada
 
def partida(): 
    print(" ")
    n = int(input("Quantas peças? "))
    m = int(input("Limite de peças por jogada? "))

    is_computer_turn = True
    if False:
        print("O computador começa!")
    if n % (m+1) == 0: is_computer_turn = False
    if True:
        print("Você começa!")

    while n > 0: 
        if is_computer_turn:
            jogada = computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
            is_computer_turn = False
            print("Computador tirou {} peças.".format(jogada))
        else:
            jogada = usuario_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
            is_computer_turn = True
            print("Você tirou {} peças.".format(jogada))
        n = n - jogada
        print("Agora restam {} peças no tabuleiro.\n".format(n))
    if is_computer_turn:
        print("Você ganhou!")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Fim de jogo! O computador ganhou!")
        return 0
 
def campeonato():
    usuario = 0
    computador = 0
    for _ in range(3):
        vencedor = partida()
        if vencedor == 1:
            usuario = usuario + 1
        else:
            computador = computador + 1
    print("******* Final do campeonato! *******")
    print("Placar: Você  {} x {}  Computador".format(usuario, computador))
 
while tipo_jogo == 0:
    print("Bem-vindo ao jogo do NIM! Escolha:")
    print(" ")
    print("1 - Para jogar uma partida isolada")
    print("2 - Para jogar um campeonato")

    tipo_jogo = int(input("Sua opção: "))
    print(" ")

    if tipo_jogo == 1:
        print("Voce escolheu partida isolada!")
        partida()
        break
    if tipo_jogo == 2:
        print("Voce escolheu um campeonato!")
        campeonato()
        break
    else:
        print("Opção inválida!")
        tipo_jogo = 0
```

Comment: O enunciado da pergunta citada diz: "Se n é múltiplo de (m+1), o computador deve ser "generoso" e convidar o jogador a iniciar a partida.". O trecho de código que executa esta lógica se encontra na linha 60, utilizando os valores de `n` e `m` lidos nas linhas 53 e 54. Por exemplo, se você colocar o jogo para 6 peças com um limite de peças igual a 2, o usuário começará jogando, pois 6 é múltiplo de (2+1).

Comment: Ok, então tem alguma parte no código que faz o computador não começar, e eu não consigo achar, coloquei o código aí em cima pra darem uma olhada.

Comment: "O resultado dos testes com seu programa foi: ***** [0.32 pontos]: Checando partida unica (n = 5, m = 3, jogadas = (1,)) - Falhou ***** AssertionError: Deveria comecar com o computador ***** [0.32 pontos]: Checando partida unica (n = 5, m = 3, jogadas = (2,)) - Falhou ***** AssertionError: Deveria comecar com o computador ***** [0.32 pontos]: Checando partida unica (n = 11, m = 3, jogadas = (2, 3)) - Falhou ***** AssertionError: Deveria comecar com o computador" Esses são os erros

Comment: Parece que você está testando o código com alguma ferramenta e, provavelmente, o código que fiz na outra pergunta não se enquadra em todos os requisitos do seu problema. Edite a pergunta e coloque o enunciado da sua questão que ficará mais fácil de analisar o que precisa ser adaptado.

Comment: Ok, tá editado.

Comment: É exatamente o mesmo enunciado ou você apenas copiou? Veja que a saída esperada é diferente da que o código gera, você precisará adaptar as mensagens.

Comment: Eu copiei, esse é um enunciado do site, é isso que pede pra ser feito, e o programa é um exemplo também.

Comment: Só tava precisando de uma luz, ando meio perdido nos exercícios.

Comment: Não há necessidade de editar o titulo colocando "solucionado" ou "não solucionado". Não funcionamos como foruns. Como não obteve resposta que solucionasse o problema, siga as recomendações que lhe fiz na outra pergunta.

Comment: Está editada agora. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O texto da outra está bem melhor e menor que este, está bem mais facil de entender, não é mais fácil aproveitar o corpo da outra pergunta como edição desta?

Comment: Editada novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Basta ajustar o seguinte trecho de código. Deste modo sua aplicação vai questionar quem deve iniciar o jogo.

```
# Define uma variável para controlar a vez do computador:
inicio = input("Deseja ser você o primeiro a jogar? S/N ").strip().lower()
is_computer_turn = False if inicio in ['s', 'y', 'sim', 'yes'] else True
```

Dicas:
**strip()** faz com que espaços em branco no inicio ou fim da linha sejam removidos
**lower()** torna o texto todo em letra minúscula
Isso facilita na hora de usar uma comparação entre strings.

Comment: Isso ajuda muito, obrigado, mas dá erro porque não foi o que foi pedido

Answer (score 0):

Usei o Código abaixo, que foi uma contribuição dos amigos e dei uma melhorada

```
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m):
    computadorRemove = 1

    while computadorRemove != m:
        if (n - computadorRemove) % (m+1) == 0:
            return computadorRemove

        else:
            computadorRemove += 1

    return computadorRemove


def usuario_escolhe_jogada(n, m):
    jogadaValida = False

    while not jogadaValida:
        jogadorRemove = int(input('Quantas peças você vai tirar? '))
        if jogadorRemove > m or jogadorRemove < 1:
            print()
            print('Oops! Jogada inválida! Tente de novo.')
            print()

        else:
            jogadaValida = True

    return jogadorRemove


def campeonato():
    nRodada = 1
    while nRodada <= 3:
        print()
        print('**** Rodada', nRodada, '****')
        print()
        partida()
        nRodada += 1
    print()
    print('Placar: Você 0 X 3 Computador')


def partida():
    n = int(input('Quantas peças? '))

    m = int(input('Limite de peças por jogada? '))

    vezDoPC = False

    if n % (m+1) == 0:
        print()
        print('Voce começa!')

    else:
        print()
        print('Computador começa!')
        vezDoPC = True

    while n > 0:
        if vezDoPC:
            computadorRemove = computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
            n = n - computadorRemove
            if computadorRemove == 1:
                print()
                print('O computador tirou uma peça')
            else:
                print()
                print('O computador tirou', computadorRemove, 'peças')

            vezDoPC = False
        else:
            jogadorRemove = usuario_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
            n = n - jogadorRemove
            if jogadorRemove == 1:
                print()
                print('Você tirou uma peça')
            else:
                print()
                print('Você tirou', jogadorRemove, 'peças')
            vezDoPC = True
        if n == 1:
            print('Agora resta apenas uma peça no tabuleiro.')
            print()
        else:
            if n != 0:
                print('Agora restam,', n, 'peças no tabuleiro.')
                print()

    print('Fim do jogo! O computador ganhou!')

print('Bem-vindo ao jogo do NIM! Escolha:')
print()

print('1 - para jogar uma partida isolada')

tipoDePartida = int(input('2 - para jogar um campeonato '))

if tipoDePartida == 2:
    print()
    print('Voce escolheu um campeonato!')
    print()
    campeonato()
else:
    if tipoDePartida == 1:
        print()
        partida()
```